# Why can't I have properties called "id" and "set_id" in the same class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, properties

I'm trying to consume a Web API. I created a class so that I can deserialize the data I get back. The problem is that the returned object has these two properties:

```
public string id { get; set; }
public string set_id { get; set; }
```

The `set_id` related to "sets". The compiler is throwing an error on the `set;` from the `id` property, saying that it already contains a definition for `set_id`.

> CS0102 The type 'MyClass' already contains a definition for 'set_id'

Is there any way to solve this without renaming the property?

Comment: If this class is under your control, you can rename it to `SetId` and add attribute `[JsonPropertyName("set_id")]` to it. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-7-0

Comment: I don't understand this enough for a complete answer, but it's something to do with how properties are actually syntactic sugar and what IL gets produced by the compiler. See in this IL code that there is a method called `set_id` generated for you. https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQGED2AbbEDGMAlpgHYAyRMECU2yANDCEdgD4ACATAIwCwAKA4BmAATdR6UQG9BASBHieABlFEAJjNEBzCDADco5HsMBfeQHoLijiqN6A+hq26D9t+YGmgA==

Comment: @gunr2171 wow, thanks for this clarification. I thought it might be something like this, but couldn't confirm anywhere.

Comment: @gunr2171 the C# standard explains it here: [14.3.10.2 Member names reserved for properties](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/standard-v6/standard/classes.md#143102-member-names-reserved-for-properties)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would recommend using JsonPropertyName

For example:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
        public class Class1
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            [JsonPropertyName("set_id")]
            public string setId { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

this attribute based on your json library , if you use newtonsoft it would be `JsonProperty`

---

**Lets findout why we can't have a 2 variable with names id and set_id together**

For understanding this we are going to see IL generated code by c# compiler

for class with 1 property id generated IL looks like this :

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit ConsoleApp1.Test
    extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
{
    .custom instance void System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContextAttribute::.ctor(uint8) = (
        01 00 01 00 00
    )
    .custom instance void System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute::.ctor(uint8) = (
        01 00 00 00 00
    )
    // Fields
    .field private string '<id>k__BackingField'
    .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState) = (
        01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    )

    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname 
        instance string **get_id** () cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x20b8
        // Header size: 1
        // Code size: 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldfld string ConsoleApp1.Test::'<id>k__BackingField'
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method Test::get_id

    .method public hidebysig specialname 
        instance void set_id (
            string 'value'
        ) cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x20c0
        // Header size: 1
        // Code size: 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldarg.1
        IL_0002: stfld string ConsoleApp1.Test::'<id>k__BackingField'
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method Test::set_id

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x20c9
        // Header size: 1
        // Code size: 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [System.Runtime]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: nop
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method Test::.ctor

    // Properties
    .property instance string id()
    {
        .get instance string ConsoleApp1.Test::get_id()
        .set instance void ConsoleApp1.Test::set_id(string)
    }

} // end of class ConsoleApp1.Test
```

In this code you can see getter and setter method are transformed to some 2 methods named set_id and get_id (set_id = set , get_id = get)

Now we have set_id and get_id **reserved** so we can't have other field with name set_id or get_id

Answer (score 0):

The code generated by C# compiler creates setters and getters.
`set_id` will be created for `id` property you have.
I would simply rename your `set_id` to `setId` or `IdOfSet` ...etc.

Generally, for property names in C#, it is not a good idea to have underscores if you want to follow the accepted code style patterns.